# How to add combobox or checkbox to existing record of "Datagridview" not in a new column

Tags: c#, checkbox, datagridview

In my code I want to add checkbox to "Datagridview" results, I have already find solutions how to add combobox or checkbox for datagridview but with ADDING NEW COLUMN, I want to add the checkbox to existing result, I'll explain to you in details,

If I have a results for "Select statement" to show this data:
[image]

I don't want to add new column at last or first, i want to put the checkboxes at the last column "Status" (which is coming from database) , to modify its result and update the existing records at the database for same column.

Or to add combobox for this column with predefined collection to let the user to modify the status from "pending" to "accepted" or "rejected" but in same record not in a new column.

This is what I want to do:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to [so]. All the code you need is here: [Controls in DataGridView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15238322/controls-in-the-same-datagridview-column-dont-render-while-initializing-grid). Just use the ComboBox method as the Checkbox in a cell with Text will require a lot of custom coding.

Comment: @Ahmed as always, something which `require a lot of custom coding` in winforms can be achieved with 2 lines of XAML. If you need advanced UI capabilities (such as being able to put something inside a grid cell/listbox/combobox different from the default stuff, I strongly suggest switching to any of the current (<10 years old), hardware-accelerated, vector-based, faster, more scalable, XAML-based technologies.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Form1()
{
        InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        AddComboxBoxControlsInGridViewColumn();
}

private void AddComboxBoxControlsInGridViewColumn()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Status");
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add("");
    }
    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    this.dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 200;

    DataGridViewComboBoxCell ComboBoxCell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
    ComboBoxCell.Items.AddRange(new string[] { "Pending","Accepted","Rejected" });
    this.dataGridView1[0, 0] = ComboBoxCell;
    this.dataGridView1[0, 0].Value = "Accepted";
}
```