# how to add ellipse button and textbox in current cell of datagridview in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

i want to add an ellipse button and textbox control in current cell of my datagridview. By clicking on ellipse button i want to open a custom calculator and result of it will show in textbox. I have already develop custom calculator. I just want to show ellipse button and textbox control in current selected cell. If i leave a cell, then value of textbox control should assign to cell which has lefted. Following is the screenshot.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to create custom `EditingControl`, `Cell` and `Column` classes as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730881(v=vs.80).aspx

I've created sample application for you. See download link below.
Contents:

- **TextButton** control
  UserControl containing TextBox without border and simple button.
  [image]
- Simple **Edit Form**
  Any simple dialog form, returning `DialogResult`.
  [image]
- **DataGridViewTextButtonEditingControl** class
  We need to inherit from our `TextButton` control and to implement `IDataGridViewEditingControl` interface here.

  ```
   internal class DataGridViewTextButtonEditingControl : TextButton, IDataGridViewEditingControl
   {
       public DataGridViewTextButtonEditingControl()
       {
           InnerTextBox.TextChanged += (o, e) => NotifyDataGridViewOfValueChange();
       }

       public void ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl(DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
       {
           Font = dataGridViewCellStyle.Font;
           if (dataGridViewCellStyle.BackColor.A < 255)
           {
               Color opaqueBackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, dataGridViewCellStyle.BackColor);
               BackColor = opaqueBackColor;
               EditingControlDataGridView.EditingPanel.BackColor = opaqueBackColor;
           }
           else
           {
               BackColor = dataGridViewCellStyle.BackColor;
           }
           ForeColor = dataGridViewCellStyle.ForeColor;
       }

       public bool EditingControlWantsInputKey(Keys keyData, bool dataGridViewWantsInputKey)
       {
           TextBox textBox = InnerTextBox;
           switch (keyData & Keys.KeyCode)
           {
               case Keys.Right:
                   {
                       if (textBox != null)
                       {
                           // If the end of the selection is at the end of the string,
                           // let the DataGridView treat the key message
                           if ((RightToLeft == RightToLeft.No && !(textBox.SelectionLength == 0 && textBox.SelectionStart == textBox.Text.Length)) ||
                               (RightToLeft == RightToLeft.Yes && !(textBox.SelectionLength == 0 && textBox.SelectionStart == 0)))
                           {
                               return true;
                           }
                       }
                       break;
                   }

               case Keys.Left:
                   {
                       if (textBox != null)
                       {
                           // If the end of the selection is at the begining of the string
                           // or if the entire text is selected and we did not start editing,
                           // send this character to the dataGridView, else process the key message
                           if ((RightToLeft == RightToLeft.No && !(textBox.SelectionLength == 0 && textBox.SelectionStart == 0)) ||
                               (RightToLeft == RightToLeft.Yes && !(textBox.SelectionLength == 0 && textBox.SelectionStart == textBox.Text.Length)))
                           {
                               return true;
                           }
                       }
                       break;
                   }

               case Keys.Home:
               case Keys.End:
                   {
                       // Let the grid handle the key if the entire text is selected.
                       if (textBox != null)
                       {
                           if (textBox.SelectionLength != textBox.Text.Length)
                           {
                               return true;
                           }
                       }
                       break;
                   }

               case Keys.Delete:
                   {
                       // Let the grid handle the key if the carret is at the end of the text.
                       if (textBox != null)
                       {
                           if (textBox.SelectionLength > 0 ||
                               textBox.SelectionStart < textBox.Text.Length)
                           {
                               return true;
                           }
                       }
                       break;
                   }
           }
           return !dataGridViewWantsInputKey;
       }

       public object GetEditingControlFormattedValue(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context)
       {
           return Text; // Convert.ChangeType(Text, typeof(int));
       }

       public void PrepareEditingControlForEdit(bool selectAll)
       {
           if (selectAll)
           {
               InnerTextBox.SelectAll();
           }
           else
           {
               // Do not select all the text, but
               // position the caret at the end of the text
               InnerTextBox.SelectionStart = InnerTextBox.Text.Length;
           }
       }

       public DataGridView EditingControlDataGridView { get; set; }
       public object EditingControlFormattedValue { get; set; }
       public int EditingControlRowIndex { get; set; }
       public bool EditingControlValueChanged { get; set; }
       public Cursor EditingPanelCursor { get; private set; }
       public bool RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange { get; private set; }

       protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
       {
           base.OnTextChanged(e);
           NotifyDataGridViewOfValueChange();
       }

       private void NotifyDataGridViewOfValueChange()
       {
           if (!EditingControlValueChanged)
           {
               EditingControlValueChanged = true;
               EditingControlDataGridView.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
           }
       }
   }
  ```
- **DataGridViewTextButtonCell** class
  We need to inherit from the `DataGridViewCell` to implement `DataGridViewTextButtonEditingControl` initialization, cell painting and (important!) cloning.
  Without overriding the `Clone()` method, we will not be able to set properties of a newly created instances.

  ```
   internal sealed class DataGridViewTextButtonCell : DataGridViewCell
   {
       private const byte DATAGRIDVIEWTEXTBOXCELL_horizontalTextOffsetLeft = 3;
       private const byte DATAGRIDVIEWTEXTBOXCELL_horizontalTextOffsetRight = 4;
       private const byte DATAGRIDVIEWTEXTBOXCELL_horizontalTextMarginLeft = 0;
       private const byte DATAGRIDVIEWTEXTBOXCELL_horizontalTextMarginRight = 0;
       private const byte DATAGRIDVIEWTEXTBOXCELL_verticalTextOffsetTop = 2;
       private const byte DATAGRIDVIEWTEXTBOXCELL_verticalTextOffsetBottom = 1;
       private const byte DATAGRIDVIEWTEXTBOXCELL_verticalTextMarginTopWithWrapping = 1;
       private const byte DATAGRIDVIEWTEXTBOXCELL_verticalTextMarginTopWithoutWrapping = 2;
       private const byte DATAGRIDVIEWTEXTBOXCELL_verticalTextMarginBottom = 1;

       // Type of this cell's editing control
       private static readonly Type defaultEditType = typeof(DataGridViewTextButtonEditingControl);
       // Type of this cell's value. The formatted value type is string, the same as the base class DataGridViewTextBoxCell
       private static readonly Type defaultValueType = typeof(string);

       public override object Clone()
       {
           DataGridViewTextButtonCell cell = base.Clone() as DataGridViewTextButtonCell;
           if (cell != null)
           {
               cell.ButtonClickHandler = ButtonClickHandler;
           }
           return cell;
       }

       /// <summary>
       /// Adjusts the location and size of the editing control given the alignment characteristics of the cell
       /// </summary>
       private Rectangle GetAdjustedEditingControlBounds(Rectangle editingControlBounds, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle)
       {
           // Add a 1 pixel padding on the left and right of the editing control
           editingControlBounds.X += 1;
           editingControlBounds.Width = Math.Max(0, editingControlBounds.Width - 2);

           // Adjust the vertical location of the editing control:
           int preferredHeight = cellStyle.Font.Height + 3;
           if (preferredHeight < editingControlBounds.Height)
           {
               switch (cellStyle.Alignment)
               {
                   case DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft:
                   case DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter:
                   case DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight:
                       editingControlBounds.Y += (editingControlBounds.Height - preferredHeight) / 2;
                       break;
                   case DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomLeft:
                   case DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomCenter:
                   case DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomRight:
                       editingControlBounds.Y += editingControlBounds.Height - preferredHeight;
                       break;
               }
           }

           return editingControlBounds;
       }

       public override void InitializeEditingControl(int rowIndex, object initialFormattedValue, DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
       {
           base.InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex, initialFormattedValue, dataGridViewCellStyle);
           TextButton textButton = DataGridView.EditingControl as TextButton;
           if (textButton != null)
           {
               //textButton.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
               string initialFormattedValueStr = initialFormattedValue as string;
               textButton.Text = initialFormattedValueStr;
               if (ButtonClickHandler != null)
                   textButton.ButtonClick += ButtonClickHandler;
           }
       }

       public override void DetachEditingControl()
       {
           base.DetachEditingControl();
           TextButton textButton = DataGridView.EditingControl as TextButton;
           if (textButton != null)
           {
               textButton.ClearUndo();
               if (ButtonClickHandler != null)
                   textButton.ButtonClick -= ButtonClickHandler;
           }
       }

       public override void PositionEditingControl(bool setLocation, bool setSize, Rectangle cellBounds, Rectangle cellClip, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, bool singleVerticalBorderAdded, bool singleHorizontalBorderAdded, bool isFirstDisplayedColumn, bool isFirstDisplayedRow)
       {
           Rectangle editingControlBounds = PositionEditingPanel(cellBounds,
                                                       cellClip,
                                                       cellStyle,
                                                       singleVerticalBorderAdded,
                                                       singleHorizontalBorderAdded,
                                                       isFirstDisplayedColumn,
                                                       isFirstDisplayedRow);
           editingControlBounds = GetAdjustedEditingControlBounds(editingControlBounds, cellStyle);
           DataGridView.EditingControl.Location = new Point(editingControlBounds.X, editingControlBounds.Y);
           DataGridView.EditingControl.Size = new Size(editingControlBounds.Width, editingControlBounds.Height);
       }

       public DataGridViewTextButtonEditingControl EditingControl
       {
           get { return DataGridView == null ? null : DataGridView.EditingControl as DataGridViewTextButtonEditingControl; }
       }

       public override Type EditType
       {
           get { return defaultEditType; }
       }

       public override Type ValueType
       {
           get { return base.ValueType ?? defaultValueType; }
       }

       public override Type FormattedValueType
       {
           get { return defaultValueType; }
       }

       protected override void Paint(Graphics graphics, Rectangle clipBounds, Rectangle cellBounds, int rowIndex, DataGridViewElementStates cellState, object value, object formattedValue, string errorText, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle, DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
       {
           if (DataGridView == null)
           {
               return;
           }

           // First paint the borders and background of the cell.
           base.Paint(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex, cellState, value, formattedValue, errorText, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle,
                      paintParts & ~(DataGridViewPaintParts.ErrorIcon | DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentForeground));

           //if (PartPainted(paintParts, DataGridViewPaintParts.Border))
           //    PaintBorder(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle);

           Point ptCurrentCell = DataGridView.CurrentCellAddress;
           bool cellCurrent = ptCurrentCell.X == ColumnIndex && ptCurrentCell.Y == rowIndex;
           bool cellEdited = cellCurrent && DataGridView.EditingControl != null;

           // If the cell is in editing mode, there is nothing else to paint
           if (cellEdited)
           {
               if (PartPainted(paintParts, DataGridViewPaintParts.Background))
               {
                   //graphics.FillRectangle(br, cellBounds);
                   PaintBorder(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle);
               }
           }
           else
           {
               if (PartPainted(paintParts, DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentForeground))
               {
                   // Take the borders into account
                   Rectangle borderWidths = BorderWidths(advancedBorderStyle);
                   Rectangle valBounds = cellBounds;
                   valBounds.Offset(borderWidths.X, borderWidths.Y);
                   valBounds.Width -= borderWidths.Right;
                   valBounds.Height -= borderWidths.Bottom;
                   // Also take the padding into account
                   if (cellStyle.Padding != Padding.Empty)
                   {
                       if (DataGridView.RightToLeft == RightToLeft.Yes)
                       {
                           valBounds.Offset(cellStyle.Padding.Right, cellStyle.Padding.Top);
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           valBounds.Offset(cellStyle.Padding.Left, cellStyle.Padding.Top);
                       }
                       valBounds.Width -= cellStyle.Padding.Horizontal;
                       valBounds.Height -= cellStyle.Padding.Vertical;
                   }
                   valBounds = GetAdjustedEditingControlBounds(valBounds, cellStyle);

                   TextFormatFlags horAlign = TextFormatFlags.Left;
                   switch (cellStyle.Alignment)
                   {
                       case DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomLeft:
                       case DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft:
                       case DataGridViewContentAlignment.TopLeft:
                           horAlign = TextFormatFlags.Left;
                           break;
                       case DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomCenter:
                       case DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter:
                       case DataGridViewContentAlignment.TopCenter:
                           horAlign = TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter;
                           break;
                       case DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomRight:
                       case DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight:
                       case DataGridViewContentAlignment.TopRight:
                           horAlign = TextFormatFlags.Right;
                           break;
                   }

                   bool cellSelected = (cellState & DataGridViewElementStates.Selected) != 0;

                   SolidBrush br = new SolidBrush(cellSelected ? cellStyle.SelectionBackColor : cellStyle.BackColor);

                   if (PartPainted(paintParts, DataGridViewPaintParts.Background))
                   {
                       graphics.FillRectangle(br, cellBounds);
                       PaintBorder(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle);
                   }

                   if (cellStyle.Padding != Padding.Empty) 
                   { 
                       valBounds.Offset(cellStyle.Padding.Left, cellStyle.Padding.Top);
                       valBounds.Width -= cellStyle.Padding.Horizontal; 
                       valBounds.Height -= cellStyle.Padding.Vertical;
                   }

                   if (cellCurrent)
                   {
                       // Draw focus rectangle 
                       if (DataGridView.Focused && valBounds.Width > 0 && valBounds.Height > 0)
                       {
                           ControlPaint.DrawFocusRectangle(graphics, valBounds, Color.Empty, br.Color);
                       }
                   }

                   int verticalTextMarginTop = cellStyle.WrapMode == DataGridViewTriState.True ? DATAGRIDVIEWTEXTBOXCELL_verticalTextMarginTopWithWrapping : DATAGRIDVIEWTEXTBOXCELL_verticalTextMarginTopWithoutWrapping;
                   valBounds.Offset(DATAGRIDVIEWTEXTBOXCELL_horizontalTextMarginLeft, verticalTextMarginTop);
                   valBounds.Width -= DATAGRIDVIEWTEXTBOXCELL_horizontalTextMarginLeft + DATAGRIDVIEWTEXTBOXCELL_horizontalTextMarginRight;
                   valBounds.Height -= verticalTextMarginTop + DATAGRIDVIEWTEXTBOXCELL_verticalTextMarginBottom;

                   TextRenderer.DrawText(graphics, formattedValue as string, cellStyle.Font,
                                         valBounds,
                                         cellSelected ? cellStyle.SelectionForeColor : cellStyle.ForeColor, TextFormatFlags.Default | horAlign | TextFormatFlags.Top);
               }
               if (PartPainted(paintParts, DataGridViewPaintParts.ErrorIcon))
               {
                   // Paint the potential error icon on top of the NumericUpDown control
                   base.Paint(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex, cellState, value, formattedValue, errorText,
                              cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle, DataGridViewPaintParts.ErrorIcon);
               }
           }
       }

       /// <summary>
       /// Little utility function called by the Paint function to see if a particular part needs to be painted. 
       /// </summary>
       private static bool PartPainted(DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts, DataGridViewPaintParts paintPart)
       {
           return (paintParts & paintPart) != 0;
       }

       public EventHandler<TextButton.TextButtonEventArgs> ButtonClickHandler { get; set; }
   }
  ```
- **DataGridViewTextButtonColumn** class
  Simply inherit from the `DataGridViewColumn` and provide several properties that should be passed to the our underlying `TextButton` control.

  ```
   internal sealed class DataGridViewTextButtonColumn : DataGridViewColumn
   {
       private EventHandler<TextButton.TextButtonEventArgs> buttonClickHandler;

       public DataGridViewTextButtonColumn()
           : base(new DataGridViewTextButtonCell())
       {
       }

       public EventHandler<TextButton.TextButtonEventArgs> ButtonClickHandler
       {
           get
           {
               return buttonClickHandler;
           }
           set
           {
               DataGridViewTextButtonCell cell = CellTemplate as DataGridViewTextButtonCell;
               if (cell != null)
               {
                   if (value != null)
                       cell.ButtonClickHandler += value;
                   else if (buttonClickHandler != null)
                       cell.ButtonClickHandler -= buttonClickHandler;
               }
               buttonClickHandler = value;
           }
       }

       public override DataGridViewCell CellTemplate
       {
           get
           {
               return base.CellTemplate;
           }
           set
           {
               base.CellTemplate = value;
               DataGridViewTextButtonCell cell = CellTemplate as DataGridViewTextButtonCell;
               if (cell != null)
                   cell.ButtonClickHandler = ButtonClickHandler;
           }
       }
   }
  ```
- **Usage example**
  Assuming that `grid` is `DataGridView`.

  ```
   grid.Columns.AddRange(new DataGridViewColumn[]
       {
           new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
               {
                   ValueType = typeof (string),
                   HeaderText = "Name"
               },
           new DataGridViewTextButtonColumn
               {
                   ValueType = typeof (int),
                   HeaderText = "Count",
                   ButtonClickHandler = (o, e) =>
                       {
                           grid.EndEdit();
                           using (EditForm frm = new EditForm { Value = e.Text })
                               if (frm.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
                               {
                                   e.Text = frm.Value;
                                   e.Handled = true;
                               }
                           grid.BeginEdit(false);
                       }
               }
       });
  ```

**Download Link:** [Full project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2SR1OxxycOIZ0VkNk9DTWVFeXM/view?usp=drivesdk&resourcekey=0-fy2kLdsl9rh2Z8Qt1NQurg) (Zip-Archive, Target Framework: v.3.5)
**UPDATE** *(10 oct 21)*: link fixed.

Comment: I've updated my answer by adding the sample application.

Comment: Thank u so much you resolved my problem and very good example.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement a custom control that implements the [IDataGridViewEditingControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.idatagridvieweditingcontrol.aspx) interface.  You should also take a look at the MSDN article [How to: Host Controls in Windows Forms DataGridView Cells](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx).

There are also a similar questions on SO:

[how do I host a control in a DataGridViewCell for displaying as well as editing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225972/how-do-i-host-a-control-in-a-datagridviewcell-for-displaying-as-well-as-editing)